# iterating through a list of image objects to save file

Tags: python, image, random, directory, save

I would like to randomly rearrange a file of images and save them in their new order in a new file.  I have almost achieved my objective, but there is one problem.  it will only save the last image in the list.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import random
def makemydir(whatever):
  try:
    os.makedirs(whatever)
  except OSError:
    pass
  # let exception propagate if we just can't
  # cd into the specified directory
  os.chdir(whatever)
img_list=[]
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    i=Image.open(f)
    img_list.append(i)
print(img_list)
random.shuffle(img_list)
filename = input('What is the file name \n')
makemydir(filename)
for img in img_list:
    
    print(img)
    img.show()
    img.save('{}.jpg'.format(f))
print(img_list)
```

Comment: The problem that I am having is only the last file is saved.  I have been working with 10 images.  the img.show() shows each image as it iterates the for loop.  I can't figure out why it is overwriting the images when it runs the save command.

Comment: this line: `img.save('{}.jpg'.format(f))` would save to the file with the name `f`. `f` is the iterated value on the first loop, so the value of `f` is the value of the last iteration in that loop. You would have to use some other file name (e.g. save the original file name and re-use it or generate a random name)

Comment: Your stated objective makes no sense. You're wanting to copy files from one directory/folder to another in some pseudo-randomised order. But that's pointless. Think about how that target directory/folder is going to be accessed. The order in which the files were written into it can only be determined by inspecting the file creation date/time. Why would you want to do that? Also, you are trying to call Image.open() on files that might not be viable images. Do you really want to show() every file? There might be thousands of them! Do you want to randomise the target names or retain the original?

Comment: I am using it to make a slideshow.  I want to randomize the images before I port them into premier pro.  This way I don't have to do it manually.